# WaW mods freeze on loadup!

Tags: call-of-duty-world-at-war

I got a WaW custom zombie mod or custom zombie map and whenever I load it, it just crashes. I downloaded the map and it said it installed I even looked in the mods folder and it was there, so when I tried to load the map it just crashed... any help?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the mod? Did you download it from a trustworthy website? Is it a popular mod (e.g. have others managed to play it?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found out why it was doing that so no need for more answers or comments. It had to do with my recording software. Whenever I had it opened / recording it would crash the game.